# Can I SELECT WHERE list of values IN list of values?

Tags: php, mysql

it passed some time since I wrote queries and I'm in a pickle.

I have this code:

```
   SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `id_category` IN (" . implode(',', array_map('intval', $categories)) . ") ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

The problem is that `id_category` is a VARCHAR like (1,2) or (2,6,8).

Is there a way to select the products ?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: @JonGuiton That question isn't about a comma-separated list in the column.

Comment: You shouldn't put comma-separated values in a column, you should normalize your schema.

Comment: Ok @Barmar, you are right. But that may not be his choice.